# click on the android phone screen

Tags: android, touch-event

I have an app in android in which I wanna achieve the following thing:

I want to click on an image on android mobile through python script.

Does anyone know how could I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a layout with a single button.  Set the background of the button as the image you want.  Make the button width and height to match parent.  Then register the button in a normal way to start the activity.  So something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:background="@drawable/background">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

With your activity like this:

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button buttonA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        buttonA.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

When the user presses "back", he or she will go back to the giant button activity.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this whenever you want to move from one activity to another activity..

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NextActivity.class);   
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Above code will take you from **CurrentActivity** to **NextActivity**....

Whenever you want that to happen just execute those three statements,
that will do your work....